# ToC Context Menu Move Layer Up Down

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Similar [ESRI arcgis.com](http://arcgis.com/) can anyone give pointers on how to move layer up/down? And if possible include the context menu.

Using JavaScript API

Comment: What platform are you working with: javascript or Silverlight?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the map's reorderLayer() method.

> Changes the layer order in the map.
> Note that the first layer added is
> always the base layer, even if its
> order is changed.
>
> reorderLayer(layer, index)
>
> The index refers to the location for placing the
> layer. The bottom most layer has an
> index of 0.

something like:

```
map.addLayer(myLayer);
map.reorderLayer(myLayer,1);
```

for more information check the **esri.Map class** in the API Reference here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm

Answer (score 0):

The client-side APIs treat each map service as a layer, while the map service itself may also contain layers (as defined in your MXD, for example). If you are asking about layers within an ArcGIS Server map service, it cannot be done as AGS does not support it.

Comment: @ nw1: Erm are you sure about your statement? The link in my OP for ESRI.com does exactly what I'm looking to do, just want to know if anyone knows how they went about it. Thanks for your response anyway.

Comment: is correct.  You need to differentiate between map services and service layers.  within the framework of the javascript API you cannot manipulate the layers of a service, you can only do this from the mxd.  In the javascript API, however, each service added is treated essentially as a layer which can be manipulated as mentioned above by using the reorder method or the order in which the services are added.

Comment: Maybe, it wasn't supported back then but now you can reorder layers within map service: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_dynamic_reorder.html